# C# SQL Server image path cannot be null

Tags: c#, image

I got some problem here, so in case after I show the image, I don't want to change the image that shown but It get me some exception but when I choose the same images again, it works

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Path cannot be null.
> Parameter name: path'

and when I change the image and saves the changes its fine properly. `line 2 exception`

```
byte[] imagebt = null;
FileStream fst = new FileStream(picUploadAdmin.ImageLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fst);
imagebt = br.ReadBytes((int)fst.Length);

upcs.updateimageonclubs(txtEditClubNameAdmin.Text, imagebt);
```

This is how I show my image

```
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    byte[] images = ((byte[])dr1["image"]);

    if (images != null)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(images);
        picUploadAdmin.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
    else
    {
        images = null;
    }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server?  Where is the mdf file and what connection string are you using?  when it is intermittent I think somebody else is accessing the file in parallel with your application.

Comment: What's `picUploadAdmin.ImageLocation`, and are you closing `fst`?